# How do I eliminate the whitespace between input and punctuation?

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm trying to output the following:

```
What is your name? Amanda
How old are you? 15
    
Hello Amanda! You were born in 2005.
```

But I keep getting spaces before the punctuation:

```
Hello Amanda ! You were born in 2005 .
```

Here's the code:

```py
# User Input
usr_name = input('What is your name?')
usr_age = int(input('How old are you?'))
# Year Born Calculation
year_born = 2020 - usr_age
# Final Output
print('Hello', usr_name, '!', 'You were born in', year_born, '.')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `print` statements in Python technically leaves a whitespace every time you concatenate your strings. It is the default setting of that 'method.'

Most of times you'll be better off using the new Python formatted strings. You have to use Python version 3.6+ though. Python formatted strings are also called 'f-strings.'

```py
print(f"Hello {usr_name}! You were born in {year_born}.")
```

Using `.format` will solve your problem as well. This one requires Python 3.0 and up.

```py
print("Hello {}! You were born in {}.".format(usr_name, year_born))
```

Further reading: [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: If it helps you, please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to an actual string concatenation as another option:

```
# User Input
usr_name = input('What is your name?')
usr_age = int(input('How old are you?'))
# Year Born Calculation
year_born = 2020 - usr_age
# Final Output
answer = 'Hello ' + usr_name + '! ' + 'You were born in ' + str(year_born) + '.'
print(answer)
```

Comment: Amazing! An up vote is highly appreciated =)

Comment: @Richard Noah only has 11 reputation as of this comment, and can't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

A `print()` statement, by default, inserts a space between its arguments.  To override this functionality, you can use the `sep=''` argument:

```py
print('Hello ', usr_name, '! ', 'You were born in ', year_born, '.', sep='')
```

or you can use another method entirely: string concentration (a good practice to get into, the previous method only works for `print` statements).

```py
print('Hello ' + usr_name + '! ' + 'You were born in ' + year_born + '.')
```